# Evaluate $\lim_{y\to 0} \dfrac {(x+y)\sec (x+y) - x\sec x}{y}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, trigonometry

Evaluate $\lim_{y\to 0} \dfrac {(x+y)\sec (x+y) - x\sec x}{y}$.

My Attempt:
$$=\lim_{y\to 0} \dfrac {(x+y) \sec (x+y) - x\sec x}{y}$$
$$=\lim_{y\to 0} \dfrac {x\sec (x+y) + y\sec (x+y) - x\sec x}{y}$$
$$=\lim_{y\to 0} \dfrac {x(\sec (x+y) - \sec x) + y\sec (x+y)}{y}$$

Comment: Interpret the limit as the derivative of $f(x)=x\sec x $

Comment: @Wyllich, I'm not allowed to use derivative for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that as $y\to 0$
\begin{align*}\frac {(x+y)\sec (x+y) - x\sec x}{y}
&=\frac{(x+y)\cos(x)-x\cos(x+y)}{y\cos(x+y)\cos(x)}\\
&=\frac{x\cos(x)(1-\cos(y))+y\cos(x)+x\sin(x)\sin(y)}{y\cos(x+y)\cos(x)}\\
&=\frac{x\cos(x)}{\cos(x+y)\cos(x)}\cdot\frac{1-\cos(y)}{y}+
\frac{1}{\cos(x+y)}\\
&\quad+\frac{x\sin(x)}{\cos(x+y)\cos(x)}\cdot\frac{\sin(y)}{y}\\
&\to 0+\frac{1}{\cos(x)} + \frac{x\sin x}{\cos^2(x)}
=\sec(x)\left(1+x\tan(x)\right) 
\end{align*}
where we used
$$\frac{1-\cos(y)}{y}\to 0,\quad \cos(x+y)\to \cos(x),\quad \frac{\sin(y)}{y}\to 1.$$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{split}\lim_{y\to 0} \dfrac {(x+y)\sec (x+y) - x\sec x}{y}&=&\lim_{y\to  0} \frac{ x\cos x(1-\cos y) +y\cos y +x\sin x \sin y}{y\cos y\cos(x+y)}\\
&=& \lim_{y\to  0} \underbrace{\frac{ (1-\cos y) }{y}}_{\to 0}\frac{ x\cos x }{\cos y\cos(x+y)}\\
& + &\lim_{y\to  0} \frac{1}{\cos(x+y)} \\&+&\lim_{y\to  0} \frac{  \sin y}{y}\frac{x\sin x}{\cos y\cos(x+y)}\\
&=& \color{blue}{\frac{1}{\cos(x)} + \frac{x\sin x}{\cos(x)}.} \end{split}

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$\dfrac {(x+y)\sec (x+y) - x\sec x}{y}$ is the *rate of variation*    from $0$ of the function
$$y\longmapsto g(y)=(x+y)\sec (x+y) .$$

Comment: I didn't get any idea.. Please elaborate.

Comment: What is the limit of the rate of variation, by definition?

Comment: That person is not allowed to use derivative apparently.

Comment: @Bernard, You mean derivative?. But, I'm not allowed to use derivative for this problem.

Comment: You didn't say so. Anyway, using the derivative give you a way to control what you find by any other way.

Answer (score 0):

Collecting factors of $x$ and $y$ in the numerator gives
$$ \frac{x}{y}(\sec{(x+y)}-\sec{x}) + \sec{(x+y)}. $$
The second term obviously tends to $\sec{x}$ since it is continuous. For the first term,
$$ \sec{(x+y)}-\sec{x} = \frac{\cos{x}-\cos{(x+y)}}{\cos{x}\cos{(x+y)}}, $$
and $\cos{x}-\cos{(x+y)} = 2\sin{(x+y/2)}\sin{(y/2)}$. Then
$$ x\frac{\sec{(x+y)}-\sec{x}}{y} = \frac{x}{\cos{x}} \frac{\sin{(x+y/2)}}{\cos{(x+y)}} \frac{\sin{(y/2)}}{y/2} \to \frac{x\sin{x}}{\cos^2{x}} $$
since $\sin{z}/z \to 1$ as $z \to 0$. Hence the whole thing is $\sec{x}+x\sec{x}\tan{x}$.